# How do you manipulate a REAL8 value in x86 Assembly to store to a buffer? (Including Irvine32)

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, buffer

I need to write a REAL8 value to a file in x86 assembly (I have access to Irvine32 routines.) To do this, I need to place the value in a buffer so that it represents the correct decimal number.

I've searched everywhere and haven't found a solution.

Here is the code, any help would be incredibly appreciated as I'm stuck here. I feel there might be a simpler solution than I can think of, but I'm at a loss.

```
.data

TotalHops BYTE 0
BYTE 0
AverageHops REAL8 ?                ; float average

FloatBuffer BYTE 8 DUP(0)          ; buffer for printing to file
OutFile BYTE "Output File",0       ; output file handle

EXPONENT_BITS EQU 
0111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
MANTISSA_BITS EQU 
0000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

Exponent BYTE 3 DUP(0)             ; MSB of Exponent will always be zero 
(average negative)
Mantissa BYTE 7 DUP(0)             ; Holds 52 bits

.code
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Add two floating point values to stack
; Divide them
; Store result in AverageHops
; Call WriteRealToBuffer procedure to prep for file writing
; Print FloatBuffer to file
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Float PROC
 FINIT                    ; clear stack before we start

 FILD ReachedPackets      ; converts int ReachedPackets to float, loads onto FPU register stack      
 ; ST(0) = ReachedPackets

 FILD TotalHops           ; converts int TotalHops to float, loads onto FPU register stack
 ; ST(0) = TotalHops 
 ; ST(1) = ReachedPackets

 FDIV                     ; divides TotalHops by ReachedPackets                     
 ; ST (0) contains result

 FSTP AverageHops         ; stores result in AverageHops, pops stack

;Set up buffer for writing real to file
 call WriteRealToBuffer

;Write AverageHops to file:
 MOV edx, OFFSET OutFile
 call CreateOutputFile    ; eax contains verification of successful file creation

 ;handle writing from buffer

 FINIT                    ; clear everything when done
 Float ENDP
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Write REAL8 to buffer for file writing
; First bit (bit 63) is sign [will always be 0 (never negative average)]
; Bits 62-52 are E
; Subtract 1023 from E to remove bias (gives us e)
; This new value is our exponent (e)
; Bits 51-0 are fraction (mantissa)
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
WriteRealToBuffer PROC
;Save registers
 PUSH EAX                 

;Get the Exponent bits 
 MOV eax, AverageHops
 AND eax, EXPONENT_BITS
 MOV Exponent, eax

;Subtract 1023 to remove bias
 SUB Exponent, 1023d

;Get the mantissa
 MOV eax, AverageHops
 AND eax, MANTISSA_BITS
 MOV Mantissa, eax


;What to do:
 ; look at mantissa
 ; read until rest is 0's
 ; that binary value is multiplied by 10^e, where 'e' is what we have in 
Exponent
 ; For buffer:
 ; convert left side of decimal point to decimal form
 ; add to buffer
 ; add decimal point to buffer
 ; convert right side of decimal point to decimal
 ; add to buffer





#########################################################
####    Single-Precision Example Table    ###############
###  We Use Double-Precision, don't forget     ##########
######################################################### 
#BinValue   # Biased exp (E) # Sign, Exponent, Fraction #
#########################################################
# -1.11     #     127        # 1 01111111 1100000000...##
# +1101.101 #     130        # 0 10000010 1011010000...##
# -0.00101  #     124        # 1 01111100 0100000000...##
# +100111.0 #     132        # 0 10000100 0011100000...##
#########################################################

 POP eax

WriteRealToBuffer ENDP
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: So you're using x87 for some of your code, but then for the rest you're doing software floating point looking at the exponent / mantissa with integer instructions?  `0111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` is a decimal constant.  You need a `b` or `y` suffix or something depending on which assembler you're using to make it a base-2 constant.  e.g. for NASM: [Can i use binary to write integer constants in assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/34057237)

Comment: What exactly do you want this code to do, and what does it do instead?  [mcve].

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the response.

Good catch on the decimal constant, I changed that.

The code calculates our needed average and stores it in the real8 "AverageHops" , but I need to find a way to write that value into a buffer for file writing. Irvine has a routine to right to a file with a buffer, I just need to get the decimal value of our answer in a buffer so that it may be written to a file with that routine.

Comment: What, you mean as a string?  What don't you use `fprintf` from libc?  Or `sprintf` to actually write a string to a buffer instead of to a stdio stream?  You usually don't need to implement dtoa yourself, and you probably shouldn't if you want it to be numerically robust and efficient, and cover all the corner cases of IEEE FP.  Your question title just asks how to store a real8 in a buffer, which would just be `fst qword ptr [buffer]`...

Comment: @PeterCordes Again, thank you for the response. I can't use `fprintf` or `sprintf` because this all must be x86 assembly. I will work with `fst qword ptr [buffer]` and see how that goes. Your help is really appreciated, and I'm sorry if I come off as clueless here as I'm currently learning 4 different language syntaxes.

Comment: Do you want to write an ASCII string to the file, or an 8-byte binary representation of the value?  If you want ASCII, link your program with libc and use `call sprintf` after passing the appropriate args.